# Could ひきつけられる mean "to get distracted"?

Tags: translation, meaning, verbs, passive-voice

Context: a boy will soon take the test to become a pro-boxer. After a training match, his trainer says to him:

> まだひきつけられる。まだ寸歩踏み込める。紙一重の域はまだ遠いな。

I found on dictionaries that　〜にひきつけられる means "to be drawn, attracted, charmed by something", but that something is not present here (maybe it's something implicit?), so I thought it could simply mean "to get distracted". Is my guess correct?

I would also appreciate if you could help me with the rest of the sentence. My translation attempt:

> You still get distracted. You can still step a little closer. Your are still far from reaching your limit.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this 引きつけられる is in the potential form ("to be able to 引きつける"). You can forget any definitions based on passive 引きつけられる ("to be attracted/charmed/distracted/etc").

引きつける literally means "to attract". In this context, 引きつける means "to allow the opponent/attacks to get closer", and that's what you need to do when you try to achieve 紙一重 ("paper-thin margin"). I think 紙一重 here refers to efficient dodging moves (eg swayback), not the overall distance between you and your opponent. If your dodging technique is bad, you have to keep a distance from the opponent and to dodge early and largely, wasting your stamina and losing chances to counterattack. The sentences basically say the boy should correct such inefficient moves.

Answer (score 3):

"You can still step a little closer." is correct.

「まだひきつけられる。」は、「（ボクシングの相手｛あいて｝を）まだ（自分｛じぶん｝のそばに）引｛ひ｝き付｛つ｝けられる。」という意味｛いみ｝だと思｛おも｝います。すなわち、相手｛あいて｝が自分｛じぶん｝に近｛ちか｝づいてきたとき怖｛こわ｝がらずに後｛うし｝ろに下｛さ｝がるなという意味｛いみ｝でしょう。

「紙一重｛かみひとえ｝の域｛いき｝」も理解｛りかい｝が違｛ちが｝うと思｛おも｝います。
「紙一重｛かみひとえ｝」とは、双方｛そうほう｝のパンチが相手｛あいて｝に届｛とど｝く近距離｛きんきょり｝で戦｛たたか｝っているときに、攻撃｛こうげき｝してきた相手｛あいて｝のパンチを紙一枚｛かみいちいまい｝の厚｛あつ｝さ程度｛ていど｝のギリギリのところで上手｛じょうず｝に避｛さ｝ける様子｛ようす｝を形容｛けいよう｝しています。
「域｛いき｝」とは相手｛あいて｝の攻撃｛こうげき｝を上手｛じょうず｝に避｛さ｝けることができる「技能｛ぎのう｝を修得｛しゅうとく｝していること」を意味｛いみ｝しています。

I was taught this interpretation of「紙一重｛かみひとえ｝」 by Mr. Naruto who is the different respondent for this question.

---

If you do not withdraw behind when the opponent steps forward, you can draw him nearer to you. And, you can step forward still closer. You couldn't do both of them. Now, you are far from the acquirement of the skill that can avoid the attack of the partner at a hair's breadth.

Comment: 重箱の隅をつつくような指摘で申し訳ないですが、ボクシングで「紙一重」と言ったら、普通は「体自体が密着しそうな間合いで戦え」という意味ではな‌​く「相手の攻撃はギリギリで避けろ」という話‌​なのではないでしょうか。

Comment: >「相手の攻撃はギ‌​リギリで避けろ」という話‌​なのではない‌​でしょうか。  naruto さんのご指摘のとおりduckingと言う動作を指すことが正しいと思います。ありがとうございます。